# Rails news site index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Demo image:

[image: Demo image]

I am building a news site.The home page should show some category's news,it looks like the demo image.I have categories "Local News","Net News","Hot News" and so on.

My index action looks like:

```
    def index
      @posts={}
      category_names=%w(Local_News Net_News Hot_News) 
      limits=%w(12 5 5)
      category_names.each_with_index do |name,index| 
        @posts[name]=Post.cate(name,limits[index])
      end          
    end
```

models/post.rb

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
       def self.cate(catename,limit)
          joins(:category).where("categories.name=?",catename).limit(limit)
       end
     end
```

views/pages/index.html.haml

```
     .news-list.list-top
      %h3.ico-news-2
        = link_to "More>>", category_news_index_path("Local_News")
        %span Local News
      =render "news/news",:posts=>@posts["Local_News]
```

I do not know my method is correct or not?

Does anybody help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) use a scope. Your method could / should work, but scopes are designed to do this.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  scope cate, lambda { |catename, limit|
    joins(:category).where(:categories => { :name => catname }).limit(limit)
  }
end
```

2) Aside from the missing " in your =render line it doesn't look strange. Is there an issue with this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It can work well now ,but i want to know if there is a clearly way to do the same thing.